# Why does it say method nextInt is undefined and case "A" is type miss match error

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    char packageLetter = 0;
    int totalHours, regularHours, additionalHours=0;
    double monthlyFee, additionalHoursFee, totalFee;
    String input;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the your's package (A, B, or C)");

    System.out.print("How many hours did you used?");
    totalHours = input.nextInt();

    switch(packageLetter)
    {

    //it says I have a miss match error here
    case "A" :
        monthlyFee = 9.95;
        regularHours = 10;
        additionalHoursFee = additionalHours * 2;
        totalFee = monthlyFee + additionalHoursFee;
        System.out.print("The charges are $: " + totalFee);
        System.out.print("With package B you would have saved" + (totalFee - 13.95));
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you never read the char only the hours and so when you try to read an int you get a char and fail

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems here.  Firstly, your line that says

```
totalHours = input.nextInt()
```

should instead be

```
totalHours = keyboard.nextInt()
```

Secondly, you never read in any user input for the package type, so `packageLetter` is always `0`.

But the issue that relates to the specific error that you're seeing is the fact that your switch statement is switching on `packageLetter`, which is a `char`, but your case is triggering on `"A"`, which is a `String`.  Those need to be the same data type, so you either need to change `packageLetter` to be a `String`, or change your case to say:

```
case 'A': // <-- Notice the single quotes
```

In Java, `"A"` is a `String`, but `'A'` is a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

- You declared `input` as a `String`, but never assigned to it any value, so it's `null`
- A `String` doesn't have the `nextInt()` method, that's from the `Scanner` class
- You're not actually using the `Scanner` object. I believe you ment this: `keyboard.nextInt()`
- The `switch` statement is complaining because you didn't define a `default` case
- Also, `packageLetter` is a `char` and you're trying to match it against a `String` - in Java, `'A'` is a `char` and `"A"` is a `String`

Answer (score 0):

Because `packageLetter` is a single character, you need to use single quotes for the literal:

```
...
switch(packageLetter)
{

case 'A' :  // Note single quotes.
...
```

That should fix the type mismatch error, but you'll need to fix the points [Óscar López's points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680204/1175455) for the code to work, too.